# JUnit test cases strategy for void returning methods

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit, void

There are many question regarding Unit test cases for void returning methods but none of them have satisfactory answer. I have also encountered the same problem while testing a void returning method in my system. **How can I decide which strategy should be used to check such methods?** In my case Code snippet is like this :

```
public class MyRequestLogger {

private static final Logger logger_request = LogManager.getLogger("requestLogger");


/**
 * @param myRequest
 */
public static void logMyRequest(MyRequest myRequest) {
    LogFormatter lf = new LogFormatter();

    lf.addField(myRequest.getVisitorId());
    lf.addField(myRequest.getRequestIdString());
    lf.addField(myRequest.getIpAddress());

    GeoLocation geoLocation = myRequest.getGeoLocation();

    if (geoLocation == null) {
        //Adding blank object to keep the logging consistent
        geoLocation = new GeoLocation();
    }

    lf.addField(geoLocation.getCountry());
    lf.addField(geoLocation.getState());
    lf.addField(geoLocation.getCity());

    lf.addField(myRequest.getWebsiteUrl());
    lf.addField(myRequest.getPage());
    lf.addField(StringUtils.join(myRequest.getCategories(), ','));
    lf.addField(myRequest.getUserAgent());
    lf.addField(StringUtils.join(myRequest.getKeywords(), ','));
    lf.addField(StringUtils.join(myRequest.getCustomParamsFromRequest(), ','));
    lf.addField(StringUtils.join(myRequest.getAdspaceIds(), ','));

    logger_request.info(lf.toString());

}
```

I have to test logMyRequest method which is static as well.

Comment: The answer is the same as with all the answers that you claim to be unsatisfactory: if the method is `void`, it must have side-effects otherwise it's pointless. So you test the side-effects. *Why* is that an unsatisfactory answer?

Comment: @JonSkeet My guess is because it hasn't been spoon fed for this *exact* use case.

Comment: @JonSkeet I am not agree with you , because when we insert some values in our database in different frameworks normally we use void return type.So it does not mean that my method don't have any side effect.
In this example logging is a necessary requirement that can not be left unchecked.

Comment: I think you've got too many negatives there. Inserting a value into a database is a side-effect. Logging is a side-effect. Both of those can be tested.

Answer (score 0):

There could be 2 approaches:
1) Place it in try catch

```
    try{
            logMyRequest(myRequest);
            assert(true);
        }catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
            assert(false);
        }
```

Which isnt great because no error doesn't necessarily mean that everything worked as expected.

2) You will have to read the destination to check if your request was indeed logged as expected. i.e. with the expected values and format. Now this too is not ideal because you write additional logic to read the message logged by your actual method and might itself be incorrect. 

So that's a choice you have to make.

Comment: 1) does not need to be so complex. Simply invoke ``logMyRequest(myRequest)``. If a testcase method is left with an exception it fails. :)

Comment: Kedar you have given me some important clue regarding correct strategy for test case. Let me discuss this with my client as well then I will get back to you.

Answer (score 0):

If your Logger is writing to the default Console, you can redirect your `System.out` Stream to a String to validate your print results.

```
ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
PrintStream ps = new PrintStream(baos);
System.setOut(ps);
System.out.println("test");
String output = baos.toString();
//output should now contain "test".
//do your asserts to the output
```